# NSURLSession crashing from Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, crash, nsurlsession

I've got a simple class that uses an NSURLSession.

```
class test {
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration());
    func f() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY.value), 0), { () -> Void in
            var task = self.session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    // cry
                    return;
                }
                var error: NSError? = nil;
                var dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: &error) as! Dictionary<String, String>;
                // use dict
            });
            task.resume();
        });
    }
```

When I try to deserialize the data as JSON, the application crashes.

I've determined that the data seems to be of the right length but the content looks like garbage in the debugger, so it seems to me that the data object passed in is broken. Furthermore, I suspect some stack smashing as I can step through this completion handler and see that it's the attempt to deserialize the data that's crashing, but when the actual crash occurs, the stack in the debugger mentions nothing about the completion handler or any of my code.

I've seen several samples of using NSURLSession that look pretty much exactly like mine that just work. I tried using the shared session instead of making a new one, but that did not help either.

What is causing this crash?

Comment: Does it happen with a specific URL? I mean with a specific kind of data returned. I don't "speak" Swift, but could it be because of "var error" that you redefined? (the on in the `URLSession` handler, and the one you want to use for the `NSJSONSerialization`)?

Comment: First of all, get and read the errors. Second of all, check if the JSON object is really `Dictionary<String, String>`. If it contains at least an inner array or dictionary it's rather `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`

Comment: try declaring session inside function f. there's a good chance you are calling session.dataTaskWithRequest 2nd time before first time was over and this might cause a crash

Comment: @vadian: There were no errors- the completion handler received none and JSON deserialization crashed before producing one.

Comment: Can you tell what is the error/crash message ? By briefly looking at your example, the following line 'var dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(...)' looks like a cause of crash, since it is a THROWABLE function (it can throw errors). Check this : https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization/1415493-jsonobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the JSON was not actually all strings- I brainfarted and one of them was actually a number.

The real problem in the question is that Swift is completely worthless when handling the problem of force casts failing. Not only do you not get any kind of useful error at runtime that you could handle or recover from, but the debugging information presented when it occurs is completely misleading and points to totally the wrong place. You simply get a trap in a function without symbols with the wrong callstack.